# Convert char(5) to tinyint(4) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert rows from one table to the other. In the first table, the datatype of one column is char(5), but the same column has tinyint(4) datatype in the second table. When i run the insert query, it says

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'x' at row 258
```

I cannot alter or modify the datatype now as it violates some constraints. Is there a way to use cast or convert char to tinyint?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the value of a blank string to be when it becomes an int?

Comment: it should also be blank

Comment: Nope - it can't be blank because you're making it an int. Ints have to be integers (that is, numbers). Blank isn't a number.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT CASE WHEN x = '' THEN 0 ELSE x END
FROM oldtable
```

I'm assuming that you want blanks to turn into zeros? If not, then provide the integer value you want blanks to have.

If there are other exceptions, use more alternatives in the CASE expression.